# Получить объект в Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

подскажите пожалуйста, есть ссылка [www.mysite.ru/services/module/](http://www.mysite.ru/services/module/), как передать по ней объект и просто вывести этот переданный объект через print

Comment: И откуда возьмется этот объект, чтобы его потом передавать по ссылке?

Comment: его передадут методом POST

Comment: И в чем тогда вопрос - `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: Планировалось использовать API Битрикса

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/main/httprequest/getpostlist.php

думаю тут ваш вопрос решается.